# MSIEXEC Silent Mode Installation

Tags: windows-installer

How do I install to a non default web site with a silent MSIEXEC installation?

Comment: I think we will need more information (I would any way). What do you mean by Installing a Website?

Answer (score 16):

Given the lack of information in your question, all I can say is something like this:

```
msiexec /i YOURPACKAGE.msi /qn
```

If you need to pass parameters, you can define them on the commandline:

```
msiexec /i YOURPACKAGE.msi /qn THISWEBSITE=http://example.com
```

Comment: I want to install on a "target web site" (there are multiple web sites)
So, I tried something following

msiexec /i YOURPACKAGE.msi TARGETSITE = LN/W3SVC/556025883 /qn

That didn't work for me.

thanks

Comment: Well it will only work if your MSI is designed to do the right thing when you set that variable.  I think you need to explain what you mean be "install on a target website" first, because that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I used orca.exe to peek inside the "Property" section of the .msi file.  Then you can set any of the the UPPERCASE properties listed there; either on the command line or in the msi itself using orca.